# How to compare ./a.out and a .txt file with diff?

Tags: c, linux, diff

So I have a `c` program, e.g. `test1.c`, and I wanted to compare it to a text file called `test1expectedoutput.txt`.

How would I do this?

I compiled the `c` file (written in nano) by doing `gcc test1.c`, but how do I compare it?

Comparing the `.c` file to the `.txt` obviously does not work as it just prints both of them out in full randomly, but if I try compare in that file directory with diff using:

`diff ./a.out test1expectedoutput.txt`

To which I get the message:

`Binary files ./a.out and test1expectedoutput.txt differ`

So I'm not 100% sure how to compare them and know what the differences are? To put it simply, say the program in `test1.c` just says:

`printf("Hello\n");`

and the `test1expectedoutput.txt` just reads (with cat):

`Hello`

How could I compare these after compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Sanat and Mythos are correct.

What I ended up doing was doing the `./a.out > output.txt` then using diff, the diff (if the file is correct) doesn't output something so what I like to use is `diff -s text1.txt text2.txt` which will then, if identical to double check, output that they are identical.

The problem is, it was not identical and it wouldn't tell me why, no matter what I tried and colours, so I manually nano'ed both text files, and went in, and just after messing around found that one randomly had an extra space, normally it would colour the differences but it doesn't colour spaces... so that was fun.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you mean to compare the output of your c program with the txt file.
In that case you can first store the output to another file by redirecting standard output to a .txt file:

```
./a.out > output.txt
diff output.txt test1expectedoutput.txt
```

`diff` command also supports a `-` notation for filename, that tells it to read from standard input. So you can do it without storing it into another file by simply redirecting standard output into `diff` command's standard input, **with a single command**:

```
./a.out | diff test1expectedoutput.txt -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dump the contents of ./a.out into a file.
Try this: `./a.out > actualoutput.txt`
Then run `diff actualoutput.txt test1expectedoutput.txt`

Comment: You're not dumping the contents of `a.out` into a file, but rather the output of it's execution. There is a huge difference.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).